# How to replace every key in a nested object given a mapping in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

How to convert each and every nested object key when the structure and values remain the same. The key mapping is arbitrary, yet predetermined like:

```
x -> key1
y -> nested1
x.z -> nested1.key1
...
```

And in terms of a sample JavaScript object:

```
const inObj = {
  x: "A value",
  y: {
    z: "Another value"
  }
}

// ...

// Desired output
// {
//   key1: "A value",
//   nested1: {
//     key1: "Another value"
//   }
// }
```

**Edit:** I do not want to mutate the original object. By intuition, I thought of using an object for old and new keys and using `map()` function. However, I could not settle a logic for a nested and complex object with that.

Comment: do you want to keep the object reference? what have you tried? what does not work?

Comment: @NinaScholz I could not think of a neat solution, indeed. Added a brief edit anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite workhorse for this type of thing is the following little function.

```
function transform(obj, fn) {

    function transformer(x) {
        if (!x || typeof x !== 'object')
            return x;

        if (Array.isArray(x))
            return x
                .map((v, k) => fn(k, v, transformer))
                .filter(x => x)
                .reduce((a, x) => (a[x[0]] = x[1], a), []);

        return Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(x)
                .map(([k, v]) => fn(k, v, transformer))
                .filter(x => x));
    }

    return transformer(obj);
}
```

How does this work? It walks your object recursively and invokes a callback for each key-value (or index-value) pair. The callback receives three arguments: a key, a value and a "carry on" function and is supposed to return a new key-value pair. In the callback you can choose to continue recursion by calling the "carry on" function on the value, but you don't have to. If the callback returns `undefined`, the pair is eliminated.

Applied to your question, the callback might look like this:

```
REPLACE = {
    'x': 'key1',
    'y': 'nested1',
    'y.z': 'nested1.key1',
}

stack = [];

result = transform(inObj, (key, val, carryOn) => {
    stack.push(key)
    val = carryOn(val)

    let path = stack.join('.')
    if (path in REPLACE)
        key = REPLACE[path].split('.').pop()

    stack.pop()
    return [key, val]
})
```

You might want to wrap the whole thing into a function to avoid the global `stack`.